# Task 2 doesn't wait until task 1 is ready

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await

I'm struggling with async/await tasks in my view did load. 
Task 1 must be completed before Task 2 is started.

In Task 1 I do some initialisation and I fill a collectionview with the data that is returned from a web service call (which is also awaited for). When this collectionview is initialised it must be visible for the user so I hide my loading screen. When the loading screen is hidden, task 2 can start.

Currently the data of task 1 is loaded and the loading screen disappears but task 2 doesn't wait until the collectionview is rendered on screen. When the loading screen is disappeared I see the content of task2 and when the content of task 2 is rendered and visible the collectionview appears with the content.

The code:

```
public async override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    ShowLoadingScreen();

    await Task1();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"-------------- Task1 = DONE");

    HideLoadingScreen();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"-------------- HideLoadingScreen = DONE");

    await Task2();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"-------------- Task2 = DONE");
}

async Task Task1()
{
    var data = await GetDataTask();
    SetupViewWithData(data);
}

async Task2()
{
    var otherData = await GetOtherDataTask();
    SetupOtherData(otherData);
}
```

Comment: @Roma I see the debug lines in my application output in the correct order.

Comment: I'd suspect that `GetOtherDataTask` is "artificially" async and in fact executes almost entirely without releasing its calling thread - which will be the UI thread that needs to return to the windows message loop before it will start processing the messages that hide the loading window, etc.

Comment: To confirm this suspicion, add an `await Task.Delay(10);` between `HideLoadingScreen();` and `await Task2();` and see if things appear to work correctly then. Obviously, this is just a diagnostic rather than the proper way to fix your problem.

Comment: is `ViewDidLoad()` an event handler or just an overriden base method?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever by adding the task.delay, a saw that the view that is created in task 2 was set above the first view that was created in task 1. So it wasn't an async/await bug.